# How to center an image in the tkinter Text widget?

Tags: python, image, tkinter, text, widget

A button on the main application opens a help file that is a text file imported from the file system. Before the text I want to display an image. This code places the image properly before the text BUT I can't center it. Here's the code:

I'm unsure of the correct hierarchy. I have first `root`, then `TopLevel` followed by `Frame` with scroll bar and then `Text` widget. The image is in the Text widget and the Text widget is in the Frame. All of the scrolling works well but I can't get the image (img) to center within the Text widget.

```
def txt_wig(self):
    global img
    img = PhotoImage(file='spreadsheet.gif')
    toplvl = Toplevel(root,padx=20,pady=20)
    toplvl.geometry('700x600')
    toplvl.configure(border = 10, relief = 'sunken', padx=10, pady=10)
    frame1 = Frame(toplvl,pady=10)
    frame1.pack()
    text_scroll = Scrollbar(frame1, orient="vertical")
    text_scroll.pack(side="right", fill="y")
    text = Text(frame1, font = ('Arial', 15),yscrollcommand=text_scroll.set)
    **text.image_create(END, image=img)**
    text_scroll.config(command=text.yview)
    text.insert(END,'\nGroup Net Meter Utility\n','center', 'big')
    with open('HelpDoc.txt', 'r') as f:
        text.insert(INSERT, f.read())
    text.config(state=NORMAL)
    text.pack(side=LEFT, fill=Y)
```

I want to use the Text widget because I want the most text-formatting flexibility. The next challenge is embedding formatting tags in the imported text document.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can configure a tag to center the indexes that have the tag. You can then apply this tag to the index of the image.

Here's a simple example:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
text = tk.Text(root)
text.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

text.tag_configure("center", justify="center")

image = tk.PhotoImage(file="robot.png")
text.image_create("1.0", image=image)
text.tag_add("center", "1.0")

root.mainloop()
```

[image: screenshot of centered image]